# SharePoint 2016 User Profile data using move to a SP list using timer job

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin

I got a special requirement.

I have AD sync user data in SharePoint 2016 user profile services (Please check below Screenshot).

now client want this USP data a separate list using **timer job** with **custom property field** ( *Name*,*division*,*manager name* like that).

I have no Idea how to achieve this task.
If any one have any link and idea please give me the supprot
[image]